# --add-host does not work as expected. Why?

Tags: docker, dns, ip, alpine-linux, nslookup

Here is the command I am running:

```
docker run --rm --add-host foo:11.12.13.14 alpine nslookup foo
```

Here is the output I am getting:

```
Unable to find image 'alpine:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
9981e73032c8: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:4edbd2beb5f78b1014028f4fbb99f3237d9561100b6881aabbf5acce2c4f9454
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
Server:     192.168.65.5
Address:    192.168.65.5:53

Non-authoritative answer:

Non-authoritative answer:
```

While I would expect to see the `11.12.13.14` in the output, since that is the result of the `nslookup foo` operation after adding the `--add-host` flag. So, why can not container resolve the `foo` to its IP address?

Comment: I think in general `nslookup` actually contacts a DNS server and ignores whatever values might be locally set in `/etc/hosts`; but "how does `nslookup` work" isn't really the sort of programming question that's on-topic here, and [unix.se] might be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the

`docker run --rm --add-host foo:11.12.13.14 alpine nslookup foo`

to the

`docker run --rm --add-host foo:11.12.13.14 alpine:3.8 nslookup foo`

produced the desired result. Hence, the issue in the newer versions of the `alpine`.